# Python Multiple Select Queries SQL

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to run two select queries one from a puzzle table and one from a table that stores the ids of the puzzles a user has played. I want the ids from the puzzles selected and then the ids for the puzzles played selected so that i can compare the two lists to find the puzzles the users has not yet played.

I am having an issue because the first query runs correctly but the second isn't as it seems to be taking the two values from the first query. How do i stop this? Its like i need to close the connection before running the next select query.

```
    cur=connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM puzzles WHERE approved =? AND level=? ",(1, UserLevel))
    puzzle_rows=cur.fetchall()
    print(puzzle_rows)

    cur=connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM puzzle_users WHERE name =?",(username))
    played_rows=cur.fetchall()
    print(played_rows)

    not_played = [[x for x in puzzle_rows if x not in played_rows]]
    print(not_played)
```

The error i get is:

```
conn.execute("SELECT id FROM puzzle_users WHERE name =?",(username))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied
```

The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: What type of variable is `username`?  Either it's an array, list, etc., or the error you are getting is not from what you posted.

Comment: Sorry not all the code had pasted i have updated the post. The first query works. username is a global variable storing the username they log in with. e.g. jack1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in this line:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM puzzle_users WHERE name =?",(username))
```

When you use 1-item tuple you should add a comma before the closing bracket:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM puzzle_users WHERE name = ?", (username,))
```

Otherwise `(username)` is just a `string`, not `tuple`.

Comment: Thank you, something so simple.